# Installing gitosis plugin in bitnami redmine missing lockfile

Tags: passenger, redmine, bitnami, lockfile

I've been working on this issue for quite some time now and I did not come up with an solution so far. I have installed redmine via a bitnami stack. I set up git via gitosis as well, and now I'm trying to install the gitosis plugin for redmine. But when I try to activate the plugin with "rake redmine:plugins:migrate RAILS_ENV=production" I get the following error:

> rake aborted!
>   No such file to load -- lockfile
>
> Tasks: TOP => db:migrate_plugins => redmine:plugins:migrate => environment
>   (See full trace by running task with --trace)

I ran the command with the use_redmine script. I already installed lockfile via "gem install lockfile". bundle check returns that all dependencies are satisfied, but I still can't get this thing to work.

After reading some similar questions here, I guess it could have something to do with the passenger module.

Comment: Which Redmine version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out now. Sorry, I forgot about my post here.

The solution was kinda dumb. I did install the required packages, but I did not include them in my Gemfile.

Developing Rails and even installing Rails Applications can be a real pain in the butt -.-